# How can I execute a function that is inside a string from inside another function?

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a Reddit Bot in Python but I have encountered an issue.
The objective of the bot is to read the comments of Reddit searching for "get_tweets". When it finds this it will read the whole comment that will look similar to this:

```
get_tweets("TWITTER_USERNAME",NUMBER_OF_TWEETS,"INCLUDE_RE_TWEETS","INCLUDE_REPLIES")
```

The comment will serve as a function and the 4 parameters will be determined  by the user commenting. An example can be:

```
get_tweets("BarackObama",5,"no","yes")
```

I think I have everything covered except for the fact that I can't execute the comment as a function because when I try it gives this error:

```
SyntaxError: unqualified exec is not allowed in function 'run_bot' it contains a nested function with free variables
```

Here is the whole code (except for the authentication for twitter and reddit):

```
keywords = ['get_tweets']
cache = []
tweets_list = []

def get_tweets(user,num,rt,rp):
    tline = api.user_timeline(screen_name=user, count=num)
    tweets = []
    for t in tline:
        reply = t.in_reply_to_screen_name
        tweet = t.text
        if rt.lower() == 'no' and rp.lower() == 'no':
            if tweet[0:2] != 'RT' and reply == None:
                tweets.append(tweet + ' | Date Tweeted: ' + str(t.created_at))
        if rt.lower() == 'yes' and rp.lower() == 'no':
            if tweet[0:2] == 'RT' and reply == None:
            tweets.append(tweet + ' | Date Tweeted: ' + str(t.created_at))
        if rt.lower() == 'no' and rp.lower() == 'yes':
            if tweet[0:2] != 'RT' and reply != None:
                tweets.append(tweet + ' | Date Tweeted: ' + str(t.created_at))
        if rt.lower() == 'yes' and rp.lower() == 'yes':
            if tweet[0:2] == 'RT' and reply != None:
                tweets.append(tweet + ' | Date Tweeted: ' + str(t.created_at))
    tweets_list = tweets

def run_bot():
    subreddit = r.get_subreddit('test')
    print('Searching...')
    comments = subreddit.get_comments(limit=100)
    for comment in comments:
        comment_text = comment.body.lower()
        isMatch = any(string in comment_text for string in keywords)
        if comment.id not in cache and isMatch:
            print('Found comment: ' + comment_text)
            exec comment_text
            cache.append(comment.id)
            start = []
            end = []
            open_p = comment.index('(')
            text = ''
            for a in re.finditer(',', comment):
                start.append(a.start())
                end.append(a.end())
            num = comment_text[end[0]:start[1]]
            user = comment_text[open_p:start[0]]
            for tweet in tweets_list:
                text.append(' | ' + tweet + '\n\n')
            if num == 1:
                reply = 'Here is the latest tweet from ' + user + ':\n\n' + text + '\n\n***\nI am a bot.'
            else:
                reply = 'Here are the last ' + num + ' tweets from ' + user + ':\n\n' + text + '\n\n***\nI am a bot.'
            comment.reply(reply)         
run_bot()
```

Comment: ```for tweet in get_tweets:``` - you are trying to iterate a function object? Where the function call?

Comment: @der_fenix I try to call the function here `exec comment_text` . Which will modify the list `get_tweets` .

Comment: What happens if a comment is `get_tweets("BarackObama",5,"no","yes"); blow_up_computer()`?

Comment: At first - why are you using same name for function and tweets list? ```get_tweets = []

def get_tweets(user,num,rt,rp):``` Rename one of it and test again.

Comment: @jwodder You have a very good point.. Good thing I'm still testing it and haven't ran the bot with this lethal error.

Comment: @der_fenix Oh, I didn't realize. I should change the tweets list.

Comment: Ha! jwodder `blow_u_computer()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `exec` or `eval` is a huge security problem! The best you can try is to extract the parameters from the string using regex or simply decompose it using the `,` and then call your function with that. Luckily you only need strings and numbers and therefore no dangerous parsing is necessary.
One possible solution would be:

```
import re

def get_tweets(user, num, rt, rp):
    num = int(num)
    print user, num, rt, rp

comment_text = 'get_tweets("BarackObama",5,"no","yes")'

# capture 5 comma separated parts between '(' and ')'
pattern = r'get_tweets\(([^,]*),([^,]*),([^,]*),([^,]*)\)'
param_parts = re.match(pattern,comment_text).groups()

# strip away surrounding ticks and spaces
user,num,rt,rp = map(lambda x:x.strip('\'" '), param_parts)

# parse the number
num = int(num)

# call get tweets
get_tweets(user,num,rt,rp)
```

prints:

```
BarackObama 5 no yes
```

Disadvantage:

- Only works if the username does not contain a comma or begin/end with `'` or `"`, which I guess can be assumed (correct me if I'm wrong here).

Advantages:

- Since the splitting is done at `,` you can also get rid of the ticks entirely which makes `get_tweets(BarackObama,5,no,yes)` valid as well.
- We're using regex which means that the comment may contain additional text and we extract only what we need.
- If anyone wanted to inject code, you would just get a weird username, or a wrong number of arguments or an int which is not parsable or an invalid argument for `rt`/`rp`... which would all lead to an exception or no tweets at all.
- You can actually return a value from `get_tweets` and don't need to use a global variable.

Comment: You can use ast.literal_eval to grab the parameters as well. Something like `get_tweets(*ast.literal_eval(re.match(r'get_tweets\((.*?)\)', 'get_tweets("BarackObama",5,"no","yes")').groups()[0])
)` (except for, uh, not in oneliner form :P)

Comment: IT WORKED! You are a genius, thank you so much. I would have never figured that out by myself. This is my first time using this site and so far it has been a great experience, loving the community so far.

Comment: @NightShadeQueen yep, gets rid of the disadvantage and the first advantage... might also be a bit tidier if I fit it into the rest since the int wouldn't need special treatment then... hmm I'm not sure if it's worth changing the answer though. Anyway, thanks for hint! :)

Comment: @MadManoloz you're welcome ;) And don't worry those solutions come with experience. The more you program the more you know what to do.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out guys! I used `eval()` instead of `exec`
Thanks to @jwodder for warning me of a very BAD mistake I made and for the rest of you who assisted me in fixing my code.

EDIT: Don't do this. The other guy has a much better solution.

Comment: Still involves dangerous parsing and can be used for code injection. Wait a few more minutes and my answer is ready ;)

Comment: @swenzel Ok! Thank you